# Trigonometric Substitution Definition

Tags: calculus, substitution, trigonometric-integrals

Trigonometric substitution is defined as the method of replacing variables of integration with trigonometric functions. What I don’t understand is how is it that in the hypotenuse of a right triangle, $\sqrt{a^2+x^2}$, the value x can be defined as the product of $a\tan\theta$. If someone could shoot me an explanation that would be awesome.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to MSE! Were you working on a specific question? If so, please add it to the question using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: No I was not working on a specific question

Comment: In something like $\int \sqrt{x^2+4}$, when you take $x=2 \tan(\theta)$, it isn't a constant. $\theta$ is the new integration variable. So in that regard it isn't weird.

Comment: (Cont.) The only conceptually weird thing about trig substitution is that we usually write it down backwards, i.e. writing $x=f(\theta)$ immediately instead of $\theta=f(x)$ immediately like we usually do when integrating by substitution. This isn't fundamental though, you can start the other way, you'll just end up doing an extra step for no real reason. (You also encounter some irrelevant subtleties about domain restrictions that the "backwards" way sweeps under the rug.)

Comment: (Cont.) The other leap of trig sub is the idea that you can make a substitution without the thing you're substituting really "appearing" in the integrand you started with. Like $\sqrt{x^2+4}$, yeah that reminds you of the triangle with sides $x,2,\sqrt{x^2+4}$, but there isn't actually a trig function there, so why should you be "allowed" to bring trig into the problem? The point is that you can replace $x$ by "whatever you want", or more precisely by whatever one-to-one function whose range contains the domain of integration you want.

Comment: Sweet thanks that answered my question

Answer (score 0):

First, a notation clarification: when you have $\int \sqrt{x^2+4} dx$ and you take $x=2\tan(\theta)$, $\theta$ is the new integration variable, so it isn't constant.

Moving on, there are two new things going on with trig substitution that don't really have anything inherently to do with trig. The first is that it is usually the first place where students see substitutions written as $x=f(u)$ rather than $u=f(x)$. You *can* do this in problems without trig, and conversely you do not *have* to do this when you do trig sub. For example in this problem you *could* have done $\theta=\arctan(x/2)$. But you can see why this is clunky; think about all the extra algebra that it takes to actually plug that into the integral.

The second is that you are even allowed to just bring trig into the mix when there's no trig function in the original problem. The gist here is that you can basically do whatever substitution you want. Technically you have to replace $x$ by a one-to-one function of the new integration variable, and in a definite integral the range of this function must include the domain of integration. But in practice you *usually* don't have to think about those requirements. (But just to show an example where you do, figure out why you cannot do $x=\sqrt{u}$ on $\int_{-1}^1 x^2 dx$...figure out which of those rules got broken.)